# C# string format arguments

Tags: c#

I know that the following syntax works

```
String.Format("Today is {0}, {1}", day,month);
```

I was just curious how this format works?

```
String.Format("Today is {day}, {month}", day,month);
```

How does C# interpret replacing number with user defined names?

Comment: *I was just curious how this format works?* ... it doesn't.

Comment: The [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) does something along those lines, but it's a special case.

Comment: Where did you see something that made you think the 2nd format would work. Perhaps with more context we can explain what is going on. @ClickRick I also could see him looking at some of the attributes dealing with URI's like [WebGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx)

Comment: its like an array,if you pass(like in your example) 2 arguments day is placed at index 0 and month index 1,and the placeholders will place the respective value on the string.In your first example if you switch to "Today is {1}, {0}",you would see month first and day second...

Comment: And ,thinking simplistic(the array example),you cant have more placeholders then arguments or you will get formatexception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("Today is {day}, {month}", day,month);
```

[Does not work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgnAxc), it throws a `System.FormatException`.

According [to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the replacement fields must be in the format `{ index[,alignment][:formatString]}` which your 2nd example does not follow.

Comment: True, however [Roslyn (and therefore C# 6) may include something rather like this](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540869)

Comment: With proposed string interpolation feature, it would be more like `$"Today is {day}, {month}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The items in the {} must be integers beginning at 0 and match the number of variables in the second argument of .Format(...) method. Download a program, such as LinqPad, to run test scripts such as this.